# AWS CodeDeploy Deployment Order

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I haven't been able to find anywhere to see what order a deployment goes out. We have a primary instance, and then 3-4 autoscaling instances on an ELB. We selected the deployment by tags (for the AS instances) and then the primary instance by name. We then deploy half at a time. We were hoping the AS instances would always deploy first so if a deployment failed we could just terminate those instances and it was easier to fix. (Fixing the primary would be more manual work since we can't just terminate it for other reasons.)

Is there a way to specify the order in which a deployment should go out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot specify the order in which the instances will be deployed within a deployment group. AWS CodeDeploy sorts the instances under a deployment group based on instance AZ and tries to do best effort striping across AZs. If you specifically want Autoscaling instances to go first, one way to workaround is to have a separate deployment group containing the Autoscaling group.